# SharePoint 2010 LIstData Service Server Errors

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, odata

Does anyone know if there is any way to get server errors back from the listdata.svc in SharePoint 2010 WITHOUT setting CallStack to true in the web.config for the site?

The client we are deploying to will not allow CallStack to be set to true for security purposes. However, we have ItemEventReceivers that catch processing errors that we need
to return so we can inform end users that they have made a mistake, but I can't find an
alternative method to the CallStack setting to get errors back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You say: "processing errors that we need to return so we can inform end users that they have made a mistake", if it's throwing an error due to user error then it's not a user mistake is an application design problem.

For instance you should validate your data before trying to commit to a list and not rely on the exception to warn the user for mandatory fields, etc.

Having said this, you can use a custom tracer and send the exception to the ULS logs where you can analyse it.

Another option is to hook up some sort of email notification when error happen and dump the exception details on the email. I just recently hooked up Elmah to Sharepoint and it works great